# Error building Pandoc: Error in $['ghc-options']: failed to parse field 'ghc-options': Invalid package name: "$locals"

Tags: pandoc, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build Pandoc from the source. Following [the steps to use Stack], I ran

```
$ stack setup
```

Then I got this error:

```
$ stack setup
Could not parse '/home/adam/software/pandoc/stack.yaml':
Aeson exception:
Error in $['ghc-options']: failed to parse field 'ghc-options': Invalid package name: "$locals"
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Root cause

My Stack version was out of date.

Pandoc's `stack.yaml` uses the [`$locals` key](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/stack.yaml#L24) in `ghc-options`. This key is [only supported from 1.6.0 onward](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-options):

> NOTE: Prior to version 1.6.0, the $locals, $targets, and $everything keys were not support.

My Stack version was 1.5.1 (the one from Ubuntu's repositories).

### Solution

Just upgrade Stack by executing

```
$ stack upgrade
```